# Не сортируется список по параметру order в NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Мне нужно отсортировать список данных по одному из значений. Когда я пытаюсь сортировать мелкие списки, все работает. В этом же коде он отказывается сортировать список и говорит мне: unknown field name: energy. Почему он здесь не работает? Все же вроде видно

Код:

```
import numpy as np


types = [('database number', float), ('short description', 'S50'), ('water', float),
         ('energy', float), ('protein', float), ('lipid', float), ('ash', float),
         ('carbohydrates', float), ('fiber', float), ('sugar', float),
         ('calcium', float), ('iron', float), ('magnesium', float),
         ('phosphorus', float), ('potassium', float), ('sodium', float),
         ('zinc', float), ('copper', float), ('manganese', float),
         ('selenium', float), ('vitamin C', float), ('thiamin', float),
         ('riboflavin', float), ('niacin', float), ('panto acid', float),
         ('vitamin B6', float), ('folate', float), ('folic acid', float),
         ('food folate', float), ('folate DFE', float), ('choline', float),
         ('vitamin B12', float), ('vitamin A IU', float), ('vitamin A RAE', float),
         ('retinol', float), ('alpha carotine', float), ('beta carotine', float),
         ('beta crypt', float), ('lycopene', float), ('lut+zea', float),
         ('vitamin E', float), ('vitamin D', float), ('vitamin D IU', float),
         ('vitamin K', float), ('FA sat', float), ('FA mono', float),
         ('FA poly', float), ('cholesterol', float), ('gm wt 1', float),
         ('gm wt desc 1', 'S50'), ('gm wt 2', float), ('gm wt desc 2', 'S50'),
         ('refuse pct', float)]
table = np.genfromtxt('ABBREV.csv', delimiter=';', dtype=types, names=True, encoding='utf8')
print(table[0])
print(np.sort(table, order='energy'))
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EPIX\Desktop\Console\images\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(np.sort(table, order='energy'))
  <...>
ValueError: unknown field name: energy
```

По запросу CrazyElf - `print(table[0]) выводит следующее)`:

```
(1001., b'BUTTER.WITH SALT', 15.87, 717., 0.85, 81.11, 2.11, 0.06, 0., 0.06, 24., 0.02, 2., 24., 24., 643., 0.09, 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.005, 0.034, 0.042, 0.11, 0.003, 3., 0., 3., 3., 18.8, 0.17, 2499., 684., 671., 0., 158., 0., 0., 0., 2.32, 0., 0., 7., 51.368, 21.021, 3.043, 215., 5., b'"1 pat.  (1"" sq. 1/3"" high)"', 14.2, b'1 tbsp', 0.)
```

Файл .csv выглядит вот так:

```
NDB_No;Shrt_Desc;Water_(g);Energ_Kcal;Protein_(g);Lipid_Tot_(g);Ash_(g);Carbohydrt_(g);Fiber_TD_(g);Sugar_Tot_(g);Calcium_(mg);Iron_(mg);Magnesium_(mg);Phosphorus_(mg);Potassium_(mg);Sodium_(mg);Zinc_(mg);Copper_mg);Manganese_(mg);Selenium_(µg);Vit_C_(mg);Thiamin_(mg);Riboflavin_(mg);Niacin_(mg);Panto_Acid_mg);Vit_B6_(mg);Folate_Tot_(µg);Folic_Acid_(µg);Food_Folate_(µg);Folate_DFE_(µg);Choline_Tot_ (mg);Vit_B12_(µg);Vit_A_IU;Vit_A_RAE;Retinol_(µg);Alpha_Carot_(µg);Beta_Carot_(µg);Beta_Crypt_(µg);Lycopene_(µg);Lut+Zea_ (µg);Vit_E_(mg);Vit_D_µg;Vit_D_IU;Vit_K_(µg);FA_Sat_(g);FA_Mono_(g);FA_Poly_(g);Cholestrl_(mg);GmWt_1;GmWt_Desc1;GmWt_2;GmWt_Desc2;Refuse_Pct
01001;BUTTER.WITH SALT;15.87;717;0.85;81.11;2.11;0.06;0;0.06;24;0.02;2;24;24;643;0.09;0;0;1;0;0.005;0.034;0.042;0.11;0.003;3;0;3;3;18.8;0.17;2499;684;671;0;158;0;0;0;2.32;0;0;7;51.368;21.021;3.043;215;5;"1 pat.  (1"" sq. 1/3"" high)";14.2;1 tbsp;0
01002;BUTTER.WHIPPED.W/ SALT;16.72;718;0.49;78.3;1.62;2.87;0;0.06;23;0.05;1;24;41;583;0.05;0.01;0.001;0;0;0.007;0.064;0.022;0.097;0.008;4;0;4;4;18.8;0.07;2468;683;671;1;135;6;0;13;1.37;0;0;4.6;45.39;19.874;3.331;225;3.8;"1 pat.  (1"" sq. 1/3"" high)";9.4;1 tbsp;0
01003;BUTTER OIL.ANHYDROUS;0.24;876;0.28;99.48;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;3;5;2;0.01;0.001;0;0;0;0.001;0.005;0.003;0.01;0.001;0;0;0;0;22.3;0.01;3069;840;824;0;193;0;0;0;2.8;0;0;8.6;61.924;28.732;3.694;256;12.8;1 tbsp;205;1 cup;0
```

Comment: Покажите, что выводит `print(table[0])`, ну и хоть несколько строк файла `'ABBREV.csv'` тоже покажите.

Comment: @CrazyElf обновил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поле называется `Energ_Kcal`

```
np.sort(table, order='Energ_Kcal')
```

Comment: а разве оно не должно называться так как я его назвал в dtype?

Comment: Не знаю. Но если сделать так, как я написал, то работает.

Comment: @alex9127 dtype= не переименовывает поля, оно только задаёт тип полей, которым удалось найти соответствие